# How to show contents of div in @media print when div scrolls in @media screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have a `<div>` with `overflow-y:scroll` set. The issue is the contents won't show during print.

Ideally, I'd like the `<div>` to expand to show the entire contents but only during print (maybe using `@media print`)

I imagine this requires javascript but I'm not adept enough to figure it out on my own!

Thanks for helping

Comment: Just adjust the styles accordingly in your `@media print` styles.

Comment: Can't you just change the height to auto.  That should increase the size of the div to include everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set height of your `<div>` is `auto` and `overflow-y: inherit` in `@media print`:

```
@media print {
  // Reset to default height, overflow-y of div
  .your-div {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: inherit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add this style to your @media print

```
div {
   overflow-y:show;
   /* Another your style */
}
```

This will make your content visible, although it exceeded the height limit of your div. Hope this link help you [W3School: Overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)